# highcharts scrollablePlotArea doesn't render plotlines, but the markers display along those lines

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, highcharts

I have logic that is set to display data along a plot area, but I do also have logic that sets this plotarea to scroll when it hits a certain width,
code:

```js
return {             
            chartOptions: {
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                chart: {
                    spacingLeft: 0,                   
                    spacingTop: 0,
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    className: 'highcharts',
                    style: {
                        fontFamily: '"Open Sans",sans-serif'
                    },
                    type: 'spline',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: 0,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    height: this.height,
                    marginLeft: 40,
                    marginBottom: 120,
                    marginTop: 40
                    },
                    responsive: {
                        rules: [{
                            condition: {
                                maxWidth: 700
                            },
                            chartOptions: {
                                chart: {
                                    height: 450,
                                    scrollablePlotArea: {
                                        minWidth: 700,
                                        scrollPositionX: 0
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                            {
                                condition: {
                                    minWidth: 700
                                },
                                chartOptions: {
                                    chart: {
                                        height: 650
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                    },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false // hide button
                },
              
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },

                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },

               
                xAxis: {
                    tickInterval: 200,
                   // reversed: true
                     labels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    plotLines: (resultsDataNew.intendedOccupancy == 'Homestead') ?[{
                        color: '#808080', // Color value
                        dashStyle: 'solid', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
                        value: 1300, // Value of where the line will appear
                        width: 1, // Width of the line,
                        label: {
                            text: 'AIO HELOC draw access terminates',
                            verticalAlign: 'middle',
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            style: {
                                color: 'red',
                                fontSize: 9,
                                fontWeight: 'bold'
                            }
                    }
                    }] : [{
                        color: '#808080', // Color value
                        dashStyle: 'solid', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
                        value: 1300, // Value of where the line will appear
                            width: 0 // Width of the line    
                        }]
                },
              
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                        
                    },
                    tickAmount: 6,
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                     formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>Week - </b>'+ this.points.reduce(function (s, point) {
                return s + '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ' +
                    currency(point.y).format() ;
            }, '<b>' + this.x + '</b>');
        },
                    shared: true,
                   
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'All In One Loan Credit Limit',
                    data: this.DataZ[0].value,
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'square',
                    }
                }, {
                        name: 'All In One Loan Principal Balance',
                        data: this.DataX[0].value,
                        marker: {
                            symbol: 'square',
                        }
                }, {
                        name: 'Traditional Mortgage Principal Balance',
                        data: this.DataY[0].value,
                        showInLegend: this.DataY[0].value !== undefined,
                        marker: {
                            symbol: 'square',
                        }
                }],
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    floating: false,

                },
              
            }
            
        };
    }
```

Visualization:
[image: plotlines hidden, markers display]

Should I be re rendering the graphs on scroll? When I click my axis labels on the key below the graph and bring them back up they render completely, but for whatever reason when I first bring up the graph in the modal it only shows the plotlines that are in view...

I've tried setting the scrollPosition to 1 but the desired effect is to have the the scrollable start at the beginning of the graph not the end.

I should note that this issue is only occurring on mobile and tablet where the width of the graph is scrollable. on desktop the graph renders fine because it is not scrolling.

starting from desktop view and then inspecting the page and going to responsive, when i scale the page down the graph is showing as expected within the scroll, so it must have something to do with the render outside of width? I have my container set to 75% and the width of the template for the chart set to 100%.

the template, and data are defined as such

```
<template>
    <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; width:auto; height:auto" >
        <div class="chart-wrapper">
            <div class="chart">
                <highcharts ref="highcharts" :options="chartOptions"></highcharts>
               
            </div>
         
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {Chart} from "highcharts-vue";
  import currency from "currency.js";
  import Highcharts from "highcharts";
  import exportingInit from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
  import stockInit from "highcharts/modules/stock";
  import offlineExporting from "highcharts/modules/offline-exporting";
  import accessibility from "highcharts/modules/accessibility";

  stockInit(Highcharts);
  exportingInit(Highcharts);
  offlineExporting(Highcharts);
  accessibility(Highcharts);

  export default {
    name: "ExpandedPaydown",
    components: {
      highcharts: Chart,
    },
        props: {   
            Weeks: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => [],
            },
      DataX: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => [],
      },
      DataY: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => [],
        },
        DataZ: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => [],
            },
            height: {
                type: Number,
                default: 350
            },
            expandGraph: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
            }
    },
```

and styles are defined,

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "../../../styles/core/mixins.scss";
    .chart-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;



    }

    .chart-wrapper {
        background-color: transparent;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: flex-start;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 0;

        @include media(xxl) {
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        @include media(md) {
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        @include media(sm) {
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }
    }

    .chart {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 0;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;



        @include media(md) {
            max-width:100%;
        }

        @include media(sm) {
            border: 0px;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    }

</style>
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce this error in the online editor but I can't. Based on the code you sent, I can't tell if you use any framework, but if so, it's worth mentioning it, it may have some significance. Additionally, there is a lack of data here, so it is best to reproduce this problem in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sun57geh/ or CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-dor1s if it is, for example, React.

Comment: I apolgize for not mentioning sooner. I am using vue 2, as well as highcharts-vue 1.3.5

Comment: I see that you've already created an issue for it on GitHub: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue/issues/247
Please reproduce this problem in an online code editor and then I'll try to provide you with a solution.